# How can I handle multiple simultaneous skeletal animations?

Tags: animation, directx11, graphics-programming, skeletal-animation

I wonder how skeletal animations in games work. I am writing my own graphics engine for fun, and I have come across several problems with animations.

Here is how I do it right now:

1. Load the mesh with animations
2. Simulate every animation with the CPU and then send it to my GPU via a texture that I make from the final transformation matrices.
3. In my shader I multiply every vertex by the transformation matrices that are tied to that vertex.

This method works very good (until now). Now to the problem, if I have two animations that I want to use at the same time (running and shooting for example) then I have to do a "height check". It still works but I am getting serious doubts about it. If I want to render custom directions with this shoot animation (to where the camera is heading) I just don't know how I could fix this with my current method.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Look up the term "animation blending."